# Will Samsung galaxy s10 works in my country?

Tags: samsung, hardware, connection-issues, network-signal, samsung-galaxy-s-10

You may know that samsung galaxy s10 have two different versions, one with Qualcomm chipset and one with Exynos chipset. From reviews in the youtube and sites like [bgr](https://bgr.com/2019/02/28/galaxy-s10-review-supplement-vs-galaxy-s10-plus/) and [anandtech](https://www.anandtech.com/show/14031/samsung-galaxy-s10-first-exynos-9820-vs-snapdragon-855-scores), I'm more biased to buy an Qualcomm version, even though it''s not the **International** version.

My question is, would it work in my country? I live in sri lanka and is there any way for me to know that unlocked galaxy s10 Qualcomm version will work in my country?

can someone help me with this please?

Comment: By "work in my country" and [tag:connection-issues] & [tag:signal] tags, do you mean the telephony aspect (phone call, SMS, MMS, mobile data)?

Comment: Usually the biggest difference is the supported frequencies (LTE bands). Check the LTE bands used by your local mobile network provider and compare them with the different versions: https://www.techwalls.com/samsung-galaxy-s10-model-number-sm-g973-differences/

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, mobile carrier functions. will it be compatible to use in my country etc...

Comment: @Robert thank you. what will happen if some frequencies are not listed in carriers from my country? is it mean that I can't use it here?

Comment: @wydyq You can only use frequencies used by carrier in your country. But carriers may use other frequencies in future (depends on your government), therefore having more supported frequencies than used by carriers is better than the other way round.

Comment: @Robert I agree on having more supported frequencies, but I just want to know that do I get minimum requirements to use the qualcomm version in my country. (for 2G, 3G and 4G, cellular connectivity). Is there any connectivity band difference on Exynos version and Qualcomm version?

Comment: @wydyq Use the link in my first comment, there you see all versions and all frequencies/bands. Based on this information you can compare it yourself.